Mathematical Double Connections
I'm back with a double connections puzzle (link to the previous one).  The goal is to rearrange the words so every column and every row forms a connection, for a total of eight categories.











cover
running time
leaves
mean


martingale
limiting
attack
snark


higher derivative
eavesdropper
atomic event
hash


stable
trajectory
joint distribution
saddle



Here is a link to a (much improved but possibly buggy) interactive version of this puzzle.  Again, not all the categories are great but I had fun with it.
